# Naming type of an expression in C++

Tags: c++, templates, type-alias

The typename expression here does not work. 
Compiler says:

> "expected a qualified name after 'typename'".

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
void mergeSort(Iterator start, Iterator end, Predicate lessThan)
{   typename typeid(start[0]) Element;
    [...implementation, not relevant...]
}
```

I'm trying to define a type name Element which would refer to the type of expression `start[0]`. (Or generally, the element type of `Iterator`.). I'm using C++17. Any ideas?

Comment: are you confusing `typeid` with `decltype` ? `typeid(start[0])` isnt the type of `start[0]` but it returns some `type_info` object

Comment: You want [std::iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), i.e. `Iterator::value_type`, not `typename typeid something`.

Comment: Only [Random Access Iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) support `operator[]`. It would be a shame to limit your algorithm to the most elaborate category simply to get it's element type.

Comment: It does not matter, because my algorithm assumes the iterators to be random-access anyway. It probably coud be made so that it worked with any forward iterators, but it's just a school assigment anyway so there's no point in investing so much effort.

Comment: @dukc I disagree. By doing it right this time, you'll be familiar with how to do it right next time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Well, "no point", as I said it, wasn't literally correct -of course it would be a good learning experience. But I can't do everything at once anyway: I meant that I need to draw the line somewhere. In fact, It wasn't required to do this as a template at all, so I have already been more to-the-book than asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this was:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
void mergeSort(Iterator start, Iterator end, Predicate lessThan)
{   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Element;
}
```

Using the following:

```
typedef decltype(start[0]) Element;
```

compiled as an expression, but caused some other compilation errors, probably because the element type was some reference it was not supposed to be or something like that.